# SQL query to show all child record in 1 row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one to many relations. I want to show my child record in one row with parent record here is my query LIKE pivot table i want to show marks obtained by student in exams in 1 row depending on how many exams registered so in table 1 i have parent ID and in table 2 i have exam sub component like

parent exam viva and subcomponent viva 1 and viva 2

Now student query will have 2 columns exam1 marks and exam 2 marks that are marks of both viva in 1 exam So this will be in single line like

```
    student  | viva 1  | viva 2
```

I have ID of main exam that is 1 and component viva 1 and viva 2 ID is 21 , 22

Now marks save in marks table with  both ID's now i want to view them in single row that in exam viva marks is ?? and viva 2 marks???

```
SELECT DISTINCT    
    A.S_RNo, A.S_SNo, C.S_SName, G.S_RID, A.Crs_SID, A. Enr_ID,
    0 AS M_ObtMarks
FROM 
    tblAcdEnrol_Course A
INNER JOIN 
    tblAcdStudent_Reg G ON A.S_RNo = G.S_RNo      
INNER JOIN 
    tblAcdStudent C ON A.S_SNo = C.S_SNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblAExPolicy_1 D ON A.ESec_T_ID = D.ESec_T_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblAExPolicy_2 E ON D.AEx_ID = E.AEx_ID  
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT DISTINCT    
         A.S_RNo, A.S_SNo, S_SName, S_RID, Crs_SID, B.AEx2_ID, 
         C.ESec_T_ID, Enr_ID, ISNULL(M_ObtMarks, 0) AS M_ObtMarks
     FROM 
         tblAExMarks_1 A 
     INNER JOIN
         tblAExPolicy_2 B ON A.AEx2_ID = B.AEx2_ID
     INNER JOIN
         tblAExPolicy_1 C ON B.AEx_ID = C.AEx_ID
     INNER JOIN
         tblAcdStudent_Reg D ON A.S_RNo = D.S_RNo
     INNER JOIN 
         tblAcdEnrol_Course E ON E.S_RNo = A.S_RNo
     INNER JOIN   
         tblAcdStudent F ON F.S_SNo = A.S_SNo)V      
     WHERE 
         V.ESec_T_ID = 6  
         AND V.Crs_SID <> 2   
         AND V.AEx2_ID = 1
```

not working

currently

```
       1    21  5.0
       1    21  10.0
       1    21  10.0
       2    21  4.0
       2    21  10.0
       2    21   8.0
```

I want

```
       1    21  5.0 10.0 10.0           
       2    21  4.0 10.0  8.0
```

picture

[problem pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlia7.jpg)

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and perhaps make some changes.

Comment: Try with "Group By".

Comment: I am really sorry but to me your English is quite hard to understand. Please see if you can rephrase the question to be more clear, maybe by asking for help from someone close to you. Please also use proper capitalization and punctuation (periods and commas) where needed.

Comment: now see its like pivot query

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: See edits i have added sample output @AdamOwczarczyk

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot on your output data as below:

```
;with cte as (
SELECT   DISTINCT    A.S_RNo , A.S_SNo, C.S_SName, G.S_RID,A.Crs_SID   , A. Enr_ID,0 AS M_ObtMarks,
RowN = Row_number() over (Partition by A.S_RNo, A.S_SNo order by A.S_RNo)
 FROM tblAcdEnrol_Course A
 INNER JOIN tblAcdStudent_Reg G ON A.S_RNo = G.S_RNo      
 INNER JOIN tblAcdStudent C ON A.S_SNo = C.S_SNo
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tblAExPolicy_1 D ON A.ESec_T_ID = D.ESec_T_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tblAExPolicy_2 E ON D.AEx_ID = E.AEx_ID  


 CROSS APPLY (
 SELECT   DISTINCT    A.S_RNo , A.S_SNo, S_SName, S_RID, Crs_SID ,B. AEx2_ID , C.ESec_T_ID , Enr_ID,ISNULL(M_ObtMarks , 0) AS M_ObtMarks
 from tblAExMarks_1 A 
 inner join tblAExPolicy_2 B on A.AEx2_ID = B.AEx2_ID
 inner join tblAExPolicy_1 C on B.AEx_ID = C.AEx_ID
 inner join tblAcdStudent_Reg D ON A.S_RNo = D.S_RNo
 INNER JOIN tblAcdEnrol_Course E ON E.S_RNo = A.S_RNo
 INNER JOIN   tblAcdStudent F ON F.S_SNo = A.S_SNo)V      
  WHERE V.ESec_T_ID  =  6  AND V.Crs_SID <> 2   and  V.AEx2_ID = 1
)
select * from cte 
pivot (max(M_ObtMarks) for RowN in ([1],[2],[3]) ) p
```

Comment: First column in your sample input is A.S_RNo rite?

Comment: 1 is subcomponent and second is main exam code and third is marks

Comment: Updated my row_number part, can you provide examples along with columns listed in query